# The POM for jar is invalid, transitive dependencies will not be available

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I want to provide external dependency to my maven project in eclipse. Therefore, I ave copied the jar file and its POM.xml directly in the local Maven Repository. But somehow Eclipse is complaining that the POM for the jar is invalid.

My pom.xml for jar file in local Repository looks like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
  </parent>

  <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:url/</developerConnection>
    </scm>

  <artifactId>v-p</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <name>p</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Plugin required to build java classes from XSD using XJC -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <arguments>-npa</arguments>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
          <packageName>com.b.t.v.fusion.p.generated</packageName>
          <schemaFiles>pConfig.xsd</schemaFiles>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>  
      <plugins>      
        <!-- Plugin required to add the generated sources to the classpath -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <sources>
                  <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>  
  </build>


  <dependencies> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
        <artifactId>v-fusioninterface</artifactId>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <!-- FFT -->
        <groupId>com.github.wendykierp</groupId>
        <artifactId>JTransforms</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <!-- Reading and writing of MATLAB files -->
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jmatio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmatio</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles> 
</project>
```

I have already checked similar posts and have done necessary changes in eclipse.ini (specifying JDK's JRE as vmargs n all). My dependency in MAven Project looks like below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
            <artifactId>v-p</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please note that the same jar file with corresponding POM.xml is working well for my colleague in Intellij.

I am using Eclipse Luna just for info. I also have checked in my Eclipse that the Installed JRE is jdk1.8.0_144.

Also I am getting the same error when I use mvn clean install on command prompt.

Could someone please suggest what can I check more ?

Comment: Can you open the pom.xml file in your browser or any other XML parsing program?

Comment: Yes, I can open it in notepad++..

Comment: Does notepad++ do XML _validation_?  This is not the same as being able to view the file.  If you  do not know what this is, please find out.

Comment: Sorry my bad..I just tried to open it with internet explorer but cant open it with it, it seems..What do u doubt here with opening it in xml editor ? do u think that it is not proper xml file ?

Comment: If internet explorer cannot open it because it is a broken xml file, it explains your problem.  You must fix the XML so it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just copy the files into your local repo, you need to install them.  There are instructions here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

In your case is would be something like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Good to know. I did that but getting the same error unfortunately. :-(

Comment: it says "The POM for com.b.t:v-p:jar:1.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies will not be available, enable debug logging for more details"

Comment: your pom references a parent pom `com.b.t.:v-parent:3.9.0`. Is this in your local repo too?  Have you run the build with --debug?  Can you post more about the error in the question above.