# Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0:

Tags: java, maven, osgi

After Deleting all plugins inside my .m2/repository, in order to resolve errors I had, I was not able to run my application. I got this error

```
Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building osgi-simple-portlet 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.143 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-24T09:59:35+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0: 4 problems were encountered while building the effective model for ::
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'artifactId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'version' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My POM is very simple and looks like :

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fr.nixial</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi-simple-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <css.path>/css/main.css</css.path>
        <js.path>/js/main.js</js.path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.41</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Do you know how could I correct it please ? The application worked fine before I deleted the content of the repository plugins.
I use maven 3.5.2

**EDIT :** When I run with -X to have full output, I got :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.269 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-24T10:56:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0: 4 problems were encountered while building the effective model for ::
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'artifactId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'version' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 4 problems were encountered while building the effective model for ::
[ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'artifactId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'version' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException (DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:481)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:423)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Can you enable maven debug logging `-X` too see detailed logs?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh, the output doesn't give more information

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a maven project in my eclipse and with the `pom.xml` that you shared and when I did `mvn clean install` it worked perfectly fine.

May be you can check if the directory path `biz/aQute/bnd/bnd-maven-plugin` created in your `/.m2/repository/`. Otherwise try deleting the existing project and create a new maven project with correct `groupId` and `artifactId` and make sure these match with the ones present in your `pom.xml`.

[image: mvn clean install]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and build it again. Then check .m2 directory - is there anything in `biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0` directory? Check the pom file which is there. Looks correct (like in [repository](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin/pom.xml))? Build with `-X` to see detail logs. 
You can also use `mvn dependency:tree` to search for problems - [see article](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

After that you could also try to install missing artifact manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276387

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .m2/repository folder because all plugins were corrupted. Then I restart the computer.  Everything works fine now. Thanks a lot.